# How to get response headers in java

Tags: java

i want to get response headers in java.

```
URL obj = new URL("http://mkyong.com");

    //get all headers
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + 
                 " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }

    //get header by 'key'
    String server = conn.getHeaderField("Server");
```

Please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: What error/output do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
URL obj = new URL("http://mkyong.com");
    URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();

    //get all headers
    Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + 
                 " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }

    //get header by 'key'
    String server = conn.getHeaderField("Server");
```

Comment: @RahulPatil You may want to accept his answer if it solved your error.

Comment: @Chetan Potdar, can you tell me what is a header is? and how they are used in webservices?